# What is the use of Vuex in context of data paginated from backend

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Being new to Vue, I have been reading a lot of the pros and cons of its use or otherwise where there are simpler options like Vue.observable.

I am trying to understand a store's function in relation to a paginated data source. So when I land on stackoverflow's dashboard, I see a long list of questions of which there must be millions...so the app must be paginating from the server obviously. The Vuex examples state that it's best practice to fetch from the database inside the store's actions/mutations. All the examples ead the entirety of the database table.

If stackoverflow was developed in Vue, what would be the pattern for the current app behaviour? Would the store keep only the current paginated dataset or is this not an applicable use case for Vuex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuex is about a shared and a reactive state across app components (or subset of components dividing state into modules). If a paginated dataset is used by a single component only then you don't need Vuex to store the current page of the dataset.